# mPDF Error: Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, download, mpdf

I have created a `php` code to generate a PDF using `mPDF`. The code works correctly on the local. But on the server this error is shown:

> Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file

I searched over net and find these solution all from stackoverflow but non of them works. I tried all these solutions and no one works.

1- There is not output before `$pdf->Output()` like `echo` 
2- I set `ini_set("session.auto_start", 0);` before creating PDF 
3- I use `ob_end_clean` with include `mPDF` library

**But when I change output parameter from `$pdf->Output('file.pdf','D')` to `$pdf->Output('file.pdf','F')`, the pdf is creating in the directory correctly. (`D` mean download the file and `F` means save file in directory)**

Why `mPDF` can create PDF in the server but cannot send to browser and force file to be downloaded? Any suggestion for why file cannot be downloaded by `D` parameter?

Edit #1: The codes:

```
<?php

include "/DIR/cost/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php";
if (isset($_POST['hazine'])) {
    try{

        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $rand = rand(); 
        $stylesheet1 = file_get_contents('/DIR/cost/style.css');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet1, 1);
        ob_start();
        include "/DIR/cost/entere_data.php";
        include "/DIR/cost/php.php";
        ob_end_clean();
            
        include '/DIR/cost/footer.php';
        ob_end_clean();
        $dir = '/DIR/DCC/DDC' . $rand . '.pdf';
        $pdf_file = 'DDC' . $rand . '.pdf';
        $mpdf->Output($pdf_file, 'D');


        }

    } catch(\Mpdf\MpdfException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
include "/DIR/cost/form.php";
?>
```

This 3 includes: `include "/DIR/cost/entere_data.php";` , `include "/DIR/cost/php.php";` , `include '/DIR/cost/footer.php';` are PDF file contents.

Comment: try to use `ob_end_clean(); ob_start();` and not only clean.

Comment: I can redirect the page to file for download but I do not want to do that because this make user to go out of the page.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes I have used both. Also I tried `ob_flush` and this not works too

Comment: can you post the code please?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes of course. Code added as new edit. Thanks for your help. When the parameter changes from `D` to `F`, PDF is correctly saves in `DIR` .But when is `D`, the error is shown

Comment: why you use 'D' with DIR? don't use so much ob_clean; use just one here like`$dir =$rand . '.pdf';ob_end_clean(); ob_start();
        $mpdf->Output($dir, 'D');`

Comment: all part with file exist delete because if you ouput file directly you don't save that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218570/discussion-between-mjb-and-simone-rossaini).

Comment: One of the included files or your main file that produces the PDF has a space somewhere that is resulting it in being sent to the browser. Yes, a single space is enough to cause that error. As @SimoneRossaini said, a `ob_end_clean();` right before the call to output should make sure that everything in the output buffer is removed (assuming an output buffer had previously been started of course).

Comment: @Dave Thanks for you answer. I used `on_end_clean` right before `mpdf->output()` but the same error is shown. What do you mean by space. Should I change `<?php echo $v; ?>` to `<?phpecho $p6;?>`?

Comment: As I said if a buffer had not been started the clean isn't going to do anything and fail. A space as a ` ` .... so if you have `<?php ` for example that can cause the error (there's a single space after the php). Errors like that can be VERY difficult to find but are known to cause the problem you are  having.